# Sum array values of the same product

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5

i have following type of `array`. 
 how can i get desired output from Input `array`. 
 Note: `array` is dynamaic 
 want sum of `comp_size` with same `product_id`. thanks in advance.
*Input Array*

```
array:4 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "comp_size" => "4.5"
    "comp_id" => "10"
    "product_id" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "comp_size" => "4.5"
    "comp_id" => "11"
    "product_id" => "2"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "comp_size" => "4.5"
    "comp_id" => "12"
    "product_id" => "2"
  ]
  3 => array:3 [
    "comp_size" => "4.5"
    "comp_id" => "13"
    "product_id" => "2"
  ]
]
```

desired result:

```
[
    0 => array [
        product_id => 1
        total_size => 4.5
    ]
    1 => array[
        product_id => 2
        total_size => 13.5
    ]
]
```

Comment: did you mean mysql query sum or array sum?

Comment: @EtibarRustemzade yes the input array comes from mysql and i want this array according to desired array

Comment: have you considered looping throught the array ? and summing the values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `groupBy` and `map` functions of Laravel's `Collection`:

```
$collection = new \Illuminate\Support\Collection($array);
$group = $collection->groupBy('product_id');
$resultArray = $group->map(function($item, $key) {
            return [
                'total_size' => $item->sum('comp_size'),
                'product_id' => $key,
            ];
        });
```

This will let you expand the code a bit easier in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Try this, loop through all the elements of the array, summing the size values:

```
<?php

$data = [] // original array;
$sum  = [] // result;

foreach ($data as $dt) {
    if (!isset($sum[$dt['product_id']])) {
        $sum[$dt['product_id']] = 0;
    }

    $sum[$dt['product_id']] += $dt['comp_size'];
}

?>
```

Comment: Thank you @cludio